# Error al establecer conexion Jaspersoft con MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jaspersoft

Quiero generar un reporte con JASPERSOFT pero me sale error de conexion con mysql ya intente cambiar el java connection y no funciona y no se que mas hacer.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo como conexion `mysql-connector-java-8.0.26.jar` y no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error es el siguiente `SQL problems: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long` . Lo que investigue es que se debe a problemas de actualizacion del conector pero el conector que estoy empleando es el más reciente.

Comment: Usas el conector más reciente, pero la versión de la base de datos ¿también es la más reciente? ¿Qué versión es?

Comment: mysql version 8.0.25

Comment: El iReport ¿es el standalone o el plugin para Netbeans?

Comment: es el plugin para Netbeans 8.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo conectarlo mediante esta configuración: `Netbeans Database JDBC connection`, donde previamente es necesario (si aún no la tenias) ir a servicios, y agregar una conexión, luego puedes enlazarte con la base de datos.

Además es necesario tener ya instalado los plugin de JasperReport.

[image: Netbeans Database JDBC connection]

Comment: La conexion la establece pero cuando quiero hacer una consulta dice que las tablas no existen, supongo que es por que no especifico el nombre de la base de datos. 
Me podria dar un ejemplo de como hacerlo, quizas lo estoy haciendo mal

Answer (score 1):

Toma en cuenta que Netbeans 8 salió en 2014 y que MySQL 8 salió en 2018. Por lo que tienes que agregar ó reemplazar la versión anterior del driver (jar) incluida en Netbeans.

Mas que añadir el jar a *Libraries* en tu aplicación, lo tienes que agregar en *`Window > Services > Databases`*, botón derecho en *`Drivers`* y selecciona *`New Driver`*. Presiona *`Add...`* y selecciona el driver que descargaste. En *Name* puedes poner `MySQL 8`, el cual seleccionarás posteriormente al crear tu Connection/Data Source.

Comment: Al agregar el Driver, en driver class debo agregar `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` o  `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` ?

Comment: Debe ser [`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html).